# Devise 3.2: How to pass additional values to a Devise mail view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, customization

Devise's confirmation mail view looks like this:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account',
       confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

I need to introduce some IF/ELSE logic that's based on additional values I'd need to pass in here (other than `@email`, `@resource`, `@token` that are already available in this view).

How can I pass additional values to this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's currently (Devise 3.2) still the best solution to write a custom "MyMailer" (using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer) and customized mail views to obtain a higher degree of flexibility.

To import the confirmation token `@token` (new since Devise 3) into your custom mail views, you will need to write some methods in your User model (your resource), i.e:

```
def custom_generate_confirmation_token!
  generate_confirmation_token!

  return @raw_confirmation_token
end

def generate_confirmation_token!
  super
  # executes original method, from:
  # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L227
end
```

...and get it in your Controller to use it like:

```
@token = custom_generate_confirmation_token!

UserMailer.some_customized_confirmation_instructions(@user, @some_value, @other_value, @token).deliver
```

Comment: Perfect! Been looking for this for about an hour.